# No module named 'arcgis' for import GIS

Tags: python, python-3, arcgis-python-api, pyscripter

I have ArcGIS API for Python installed and when I use below line, am getting error as

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named arcgis

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
```

Please refer to Image[image: c]

Comment: How did you install `arcgis`? Do you have different Python installations on your machine? Also, when pasting errors or code on this page I recommend you paste the text and format the code using the `{ }` button rather than pasting images.

Comment: look at this https://community.esri.com/thread/202754-why-is-from-argisgis-import-gis-not-possible

Comment: Which product are you using? Python with arcgis pro is anaconda based and Python is 3.6. Also you have to Start pyscripter with a batch File, activating the anaconda Environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using PyScripter with arcgis pro you should call the IDE with a batch script, to activate the anaconda environment. There are batch files shipped with arcgis pro which i use to call PyScripter:

```
@echo off
set pyhome=%PROGRAMFILES%\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3
set pyscrpt=%~pd0\PyScripter\PyScripter.exe

if not exist "%pyhome%" (
    echo Can't find "%%pyhome%%". Can't start PyScripter.
    pause
    goto eof
)

if not exist "%pyscrpt%" (
    echo Can't find "%%pyscrpt%%". Can't start PyScripter.
    pause
    goto eof
)

call "%PROGRAMFILES%\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\Scripts\activate"
start "PyScripter" "%pyscrpt%" --PYTHON36 --pythondllpath="%pyhome%"
```

So in the first two lines (after the @echo off) I declare the locations (directories) as variables. They have to match your own installation, of course

- The first (%pyhome%) defines the Python directory, which comes with arcgis pro
- The second (%pyscrpt%) is the path to the PyScripter executable: pysripter.exe

I run PyScripter with `start` and the given commandline options to use the correct python version and path. Currently this is Python3.6.

[image: Screenshot of PyScripter]