Problem with installation ArcGIS Python library
I want to launch the Python tool, which is available here:
https://github.com/Esri/field-maps-scripts
but unfortunately there is no arcgis library

I tried several ways of installing this script:
https://pypi.org/project/arcgis/
by using, for instance:
pip install arcgis

but unfortunately I wasn't successful, as you can see below:

I also used the way proposed by ESRI with the installation of Conda environment:
https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/field-maps/field-mobility/duplicate-maps-and-forms-for-use-in-field-maps/?srsltid=AfmBOopvf98QsMThhs6EcLesW-YHz2O97TPO_5NELijzyXy1zY-0llpe
and it does work, but only for the dedicated ArcGIS Pro folder. Unfortunately, my tool downloaded from Github is stored in a different location and I use IDLE Python to run it, which keeps saying that the ArcGIS library hasn't been installed.
I've updated the Package Manager in ArcGIS Pro, but it didn't help either.
https://developers.arcgis.com/python/latest/guide/install-and-set-up/
On the other hand the conda environment:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76039176/error-installing-arcgis-via-pip-or-pipenv
isn't recognized by pip since installed from Windows directories.
How could I make this installation successful?
I need it for duplication forms in Field Maps Designer.

Why is python-2.7 tag applied?  Python 2.x isn't support by Field Maps Scripts or ArcGIS API for Python.

So which Python should I use then?

related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332534/no-module-named-arcgis-for-import-gis

Please do not post images of error messages. Images are not legible on all devices and can't be searched by others with the same problem, so you are in effect hiding your answer from others (which violates the purpose of posting a Question -- sharing solutions).

@Vince thank you, I will know it for the future.

It sounds like you have multiple python installations on your computer.  Arcpy is only going to run via the python interpreter that comes with ArcGIS Pro.  You cannot install arcpy into another version of Python and expect it to work.
Your options are to:

Clone your current ArcGIS Pro python version to unlock the interpreter.
Install any github downloaded third party libraries to the cloned environment.
Make sure your IDE is pointing to the correct interpreter.


I think I've done 2 of 3 points. Now I don't know how to change my IDLE Python interpreter.

If you are just using IDLE, then the IDLE in your cloned environment is set to the correct Python interpreter.  Other IDEs have settings for that.  You also have to set system variables for Python.   Start with these links and move to stackoverflow for non GIS specific questions.  https://realpython.com/add-python-to-path/  and   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip
